# Powershell and Teams two factor authentication

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have installed Microsoft Teams PowerShell module and want to connect to my account using the command

```
$credential = Get-Credential

#Connect to Microsoft Teams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential
```

A dialog will pop up asking for my credentials only, and without the second step which is a code I receive on my mobile, I can't log in correctly and an error will appear.

My Question is how to bypass the two factor code or how to wait for it?

My attempt is:
I read that using just

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
```

Would open the Microsoft Login GUI, then inside the window I can sign in and enter the code.
The problem is the above command will throw an error and GUI will not open.

Links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-install
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps

Comment: "the above command will throw an error and GUI will open." - please post the full error text/message and details, and describe the GUI - is it the same credUI popup you get from `Get-Credential` or does it look different?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I miss typed "will not open", and the GUI as I saw on the internet it should be not like the credential one, it should be like when you sign to your Microsoft account online
http://www.uclabs.blog/2018/07/remote-login-to-microsoft-teams.html?m=1

Comment: I was trying to make you multiple screenshots to cover multiple scenarios, then luckily everything worked, and I found out version 0.9.6 can do New-Team -Template parameters, when the latest version dose not.

Answer (score 1):

First Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Repository PSGallery -Force
then open a new Powershell window and Update-Module MicrosoftTeams -allowprerelease
You'll get the 2.3.2-preview
then Connect-MicrosoftTeams
now you get your MFA enabled account to work.
The irony, the non preview module cant handle MFA june 14 2021.
/Göran Eriksson

Comment: Thank you, this project is already finished, however I will keep this information in mind for other projects :) THX